# retrieve data from to textbox according to dropdownlist selection

Tags: c#, asp.net

here is my code, but when i replace `dropdownlist.selectedvalue` with a `real ID` 
it works well, so i need this change when i select another id from dropdownlist :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("select * from UsersTable where UserName='" + DropDownListUsers.SelectedValue + "'", conn);
    try
    {
        conn.Open();

        using (SqlDataReader red = com.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (red.Read())
            {
                TextBoxpass.Text = (red["password"].ToString());
                TextBoxFname.Text = (red["Fname"].ToString());
                TextBoxLname.Text = (red["Lname"].ToString());
                TextBoxAddress.Text = (red["Address"].ToString());
                TextBoxPhone.Text = (red["PhoneNo"].ToString());
                TextBoxEmail.Text = (red["Email"].ToString());
                TextBoxpass.Text = (red["password"].ToString());
            }
        }
    }

    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add .ToString();

```
DropDownListUsers.SelectedValue.ToString();
```

and sure like @Hung said if you want to put it in page load make sure to put

```
DropDownListUsers.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

or any default value before the code above

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of things you need to do here in order to make your code better.

You need to bind your above code to the `changed` event of your
    `DropDownListUsers` not the page load or if you do want to put it in page load, you need to specify default selected value of your dropdown.

```
//server side code
protected void DropDownListUsers_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     //code here
}
//Your markup
OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCompany_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True"
```

Use Parameterized Queries https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738521(v=vs.100).aspx